# Is it needed to increase the precision of ContourPlot in this case?

Tags: plotting, functions, precision-and-accuracy

I have this function and I want to see where it is zero.
$$\frac{1}{16} \left(\sinh (\pi  x) \left(64 \left(x^2-4\right) \cosh \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right) \cos (y)+\left(x^2+4\right)^2+256 x \sinh \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right) \sin (y)\right)+\left(x^2-12\right)^2 \sinh \left(\frac{7 \pi  x}{3}\right)-2 \left(x^2+4\right)^2 \sinh \left(\frac{5 \pi  x}{3}\right)\right)+2 \left(x^2-4\right) \sinh \left(\frac{\pi  x}{3}\right)$$
I use ContourPlot

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  2 (-4 + x^2) Sinh[(π x)/3] + 
   1/16 (((4 + x^2)^2 + 64 (-4 + x^2) Cos[y] Cosh[(2 π x)/3] + 
         256 x Sin[y] Sinh[(2 π x)/3]) Sinh[π x] - 
      2 (4 + x^2)^2 Sinh[(5 π x)/3] + (-12 + x^2)^2 Sinh[(
        7 π x)/3]);

ContourPlot[
 f[x, y] == 0, {x, 3.465728, 3.465729}, {y, 1.046786, 1.046795}, 
 PlotPoints -> 500]
```

and I obtain this plot

Now, my question is that can I trust this plot and conclude that the curves do not cross?

Or, I should increase the precision of the plot? And if so, how can I ask Mathematica to give higher precision for the axis in ContourPlot?

Answer (score 1):

`f[x, y] == 0` can be separated in lhs[y] == rhs[x]. This shows, rhs gets immaginary in a small range of x. So curves do not intersect.

```
f[x_, y_] = 
  2 (-4 + x^2) Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] + 
   1/16 (((4 + x^2)^2 + 64 (-4 + x^2) Cos[y] Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
         256 x Sin[y] Sinh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]) Sinh[\[Pi] x] - 
      2 (4 + x^2)^2 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/
         3] + (-12 + x^2)^2 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]);

eq = Equal @@@ (First@
     Solve[f[x, y] == 0 && Sin[y]^2 + Cos[y]^2 == 1, Cos[y], 
      Sin[y]]) // First

(*   Cos[y] == (-65536 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/
      3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
    32768 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] - 
    4096 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
    8192 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
    2048 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
    512 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
    128 x^6 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
    16384 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
    4096 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
    1024 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
    256 x^6 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
    73728 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
    30720 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
    3584 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
    128 x^6 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/
      3] - \[Sqrt]((65536 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/
           3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] - 
         32768 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/
           3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
         4096 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/
           3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] - 
         8192 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
         2048 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
         512 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
         128 x^6 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
         16384 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/
           3] + 4096 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(
           5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
         1024 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/
           3] - 256 x^6 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(
           5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
         73728 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/
           3] + 30720 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(
           7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
         3584 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/
           3] + 128 x^6 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(
           7 \[Pi] x)/3])^2 - 
       4 (65536 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
          32768 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
          4096 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
          65536 x^2 Sinh[(2 \[Pi] x)/
            3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2) (16384 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
          8192 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
          1024 x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
          4096 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] - 
          1024 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
          256 x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
          64 x^6 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
          256 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 256 x^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
          96 x^4 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 16 x^6 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
          x^8 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
          65536 x^2 Sinh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
          8192 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          2048 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          512 x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          128 x^6 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          1024 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          1024 x^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          384 x^4 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          64 x^6 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          4 x^8 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          1024 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
          1024 x^2 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
          384 x^4 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
          64 x^6 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
          4 x^8 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
          36864 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          15360 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          1792 x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          64 x^6 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          4608 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          1536 x^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          64 x^4 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          32 x^6 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          2 x^8 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          9216 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          3072 x^2 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          128 x^4 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          64 x^6 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
          4 x^8 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
          20736 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
          6912 x^2 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
          864 x^4 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
          48 x^6 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
          x^8 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2)))/(2 (65536 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/
        3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
      32768 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
      4096 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
      65536 x^2 Sinh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2))   *)

Plot[eq[[2]], {x, 3.465728, 3.465729}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Plot[Im[eq[[2]]], {x, 3.465728, 3.465729}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 60, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
eq /. x -> Rationalize[3.46572839, 0] // N[#, 20] &

(*   Cos[y] == 0.50035241364172394089 - 9.794261144042*10^-8 I   *)
```

**Edit**

f does not reach zero as it should, in the imaginary range.

```
Plot[f[Rationalize[3.46572839, 0], y], {y, 1030/1000, 1060/1000}, 
 PlotRange -> 10, PlotPoints -> 200]

Maximize[{f[Rationalize[3.46572839, 0], y], 
   1030/1000 < y < 1060/1000}, y] // N[#, 10] &

(*   {-7.787746817*10^-6, {y -> 1.046790571}}   *)

ContourPlot[
 f[x, y] == 0, {x, 34657283/10000000, 6931457/2000000}, {y, 
  1046786/1000000, 1046795/1000000}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 30, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but one direction to go in:

```
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, 3.465728, 3.465729}, {y, 1.046786, 1.046795}, PlotPoints -> 500]

{l1, l2} = Cases[Normal[cp], _Line, Infinity];
{{x1, y1}} = MinimalBy[First@l1, RegionDistance[l2]];
{{x2, y2}} = MinimalBy[First@l2, RegionDistance[l1]];
Show[
 cp,
 ListPlot[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2},}, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Output]

```
sol1 = r /. FindRoot[f[r, y], {r, x1}];
sol2 = r /. FindRoot[f[r, y], {r, x2}];
sol1 - sol2
```

> 3.11929*10^-8

At least `FindRoot` also finds that there are two distinct solutions at that `y`. However, `FindRoot` also warns about its ability to find roots with the desired accuracy, so it is still not conclusive. Also, perhaps it should be looking for the root by also adjusting `y`.

The idea here is that we can extract values from the plot and then try to verify our conclusions about the plot using other functions.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows that `f[x, y]` is negative (not zero) along the vertical line `x == 3.4657284...` through the saddle point between the two branches, and therefore the line separates the two branches where `f[x, y] == 0` in the OP's graph:

```
yAssum = 1.046786`32 < y < 1.046795`32;
FindRoot[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}], {{x, 3.465728}, {y, 1.04679}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 32]
Simplify[
 Reduce[f[x, y] < 0 && yAssum /. First@%, y],
 yAssum]
```

> ```
> (* Saddle point:
>     {x -> 3.4657284034593587205275273903929, 
>      y -> 1.0467905677870295818695381998660}
> *)
> ```

> Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

Another way to show `x == 3.465...` separates the branches of the curve (different, exact calculation; but same idea, negative maximum along the line):

```
xAssum = Rationalize[3.465 < x < 3.466, 0];
yAssum = Rationalize[1.046786 < y < 1.046795, 0];
xCP = x /. 
   First@Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == 0 && yAssum && xAssum, {x, y}];

Maximize[{f[xCP, y], yAssum}, y] // N[#, 32] &
(*
{-0.000037312986399805657836881071055665,
 {y -> 1.0467905677870295818695381998661}}
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] := 
  2 (-4 + x^2) Sinh[(π x)/3] + 
   1/16 (((4 + x^2)^2 + 64 (-4 + x^2) Cos[y] Cosh[(2 π x)/3] + 
         256 x Sin[y] Sinh[(2 π x)/3]) Sinh[π x] - 
      2 (4 + x^2)^2 Sinh[(5 π x)/
         3] + (-12 + x^2)^2 Sinh[(7 π x)/3]);

ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0,
 {x, 3464/1000, 3468/1000}, {y, 103/100, 106/100},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
({min, arg} = NMinimize[{f[x, y]^2,
   3464/1000 < x < 3468/1000, 1030/1000 < y < 1060/1000},
  {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]) /. r_Real :> N[r]

(* {0, {x -> 3.46572, y -> 1.04691}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Verifying the solution,

```
f[x, y] /. arg

(* 0.*10^-20 *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Using [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html)

```
Plot3D[f[x, y],
 {x, 3464/1000, 3468/1000}, {y, 103/100, 106/100},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @BobHanlon, your `/. r_Real :> N[r]` makes result wrong. Do `/. r_Real :> N[r, 20]` or just leave it, to get only 10^-11 for `f[x, y] /. arg`

Comment: @Akku14 - If you evaluate `Precision[arg]` you will see that it has a precision of 30 digits. The `N` only affects the display (similar to a display wrapper) and is isolated from the definitions of `{min, arg}` by the parentheses. Subsequently, the evaluation of `f[x, y] /. arg` only produces 19+ digits of precision due to the computational complexity of `f[x, y]`